# Wagtail RouteablePageMixin with "overlapping" url paths leading to different routes

Tags: wagtail

Is it possible to have a wagtail `RouteablePageMixin` route that is a subpath of another?

This is my code:

```py
class MyPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    @route("foo/")
    def foo(self, request):
        view = views.FooView.as_view()
        return view(request, self)

    @route("foo/bar/")
    def bar(self, request):
        view = views.BarView.as_view()
        return view(request, self)
```

What happens:
When I visit `<page url>/foo/bar/` I get a `FooView` response, when what I want is a `BarView` response.

Is this possible to achieve?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes are specified as [regular expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions), so you need to mark the start and end with `^` and `$` to ensure the URL pattern is matched against the whole path, rather than matching on any path that happens to contain the given pattern as a substring.

```
@route("^foo/$")

@route("^foo/bar/$")
```

Alternatively, you could make use of the fact that the patterns are checked in the order they appear in the code, and put the more specific one first:

```
class MyPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    @route("foo/bar/")
    def bar(self, request):
        view = views.BarView.as_view()
        return view(request, self)

    @route("foo/")
    def foo(self, request):
        view = views.FooView.as_view()
        return view(request, self)
```